# DB2 Warehouse on Cloud default PLSQL compatibility

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, db2-woc

How can I find if a DB2 Warehouse on Cloud instance is enabled for Oracle compatibility? What is the default compatibility mode for DB2WoC instance which was provisioned from IBM Cloud? Is there a way to toggle the mode? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle compatibility can only be set at the time of provision. It can't be changed afterwards. If you need to change the setting, you would need to raise a Ticket and see if support will copy your data into a new instance. Alternatively, provision a new instance yourself, checking the Oracle compatibility option, and copy your data over.

A quick way to check if you have compatibility mode enabled is to look at the following parameters

```
select distinct name, value from sysibmadm.dbcfg where name like '%compat'
```

If they are all on, then your database was created in Oracle Compatibility mode

```
 NAME            VALUE
 --------------- -----
 date_compat     ON
 number_compat   ON
 varchar2_compat ON
```

Comment: This is exactly I am looking for. I am not sure if there is an option to choose for oracle compatiblity while we provision DB2WoC from bluemix/IBM Cloud catalog? Will that be appearing only for provisioning enterprise plan?

Comment: The entry plan does not support Oracle Compatibility. If you chose any of the other plans, you will see a YES/NO check box for "Oracle Compatibility Configuration: Choose this option if you require Oracle compatibility"  just under where you chose your region etc on this page  https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/db2-warehouse

Answer (score 0):

Depends on *which plan* you are on. IBM Documents that Oracle-compatibility does not apply to the entry plan for the managed service of Db2 warehouse on cloud

Depending on what you've got, and deployment timing,there are configuration options (including ENABLE_ORACLE_COMPATIBILITY), see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/admin/configuring_Local.html#configuring_Local__config_options

Comment: Ours is an enterprise plan, is that enabled?